# Split a string on comma and space at the same time

Tags: c#, string, split

I have a string which contains <kbd>comma</kbd>  and <kbd>space</kbd>. I need to split this string based on these two and add it into a string array. Until now I have done it on either comma or space but not both at the same time.
Here is the string:

> 2013/02/05 11:50:57,00:00:17,5,9870,O,9851,9851,,1,1029441,0,E9870,Extn9870,E9851,GM  PS,0,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,

As we can see in the above string example `2013/02/05 11:50:57` contains space and rest each one are separated by comma.

Here is the code that I have tried..

```
 string[] str = line.Split(new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Just add space to the separators array?

```
string[] str = line.Split(new[] { ',', ' ' }, 
                                StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```